# Display Menubar On Mouse Release

Tags: c#, winforms

I have displayed an image in a Windows form. The user can draw a rectangle on top of this. When the user releases the mouse after drawing the image, I need to display a few buttons, similarly to showing a tooltip.

So far, I have:

1. Created a new `WinForm` named `Toolbar`
2. Removed titlebar
3. Added tooltip control on the `WinForm`
4. Added 4 buttons

Being an ASP.NET web developer I perceive the following items as missing:

1. Handle `MouseUp` event
2. Get co-ordinates of the mouse release location (say `x1`, `y1`)
3. Render my Toolbar `Winform` with top position as `(x1, y1)`
4. Let the respective buttons handle their responsibilities in their event handlers

Can you please help me validate my approach and show some pointers for the code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `ContextMenuStrip` ([info from MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.contextmenustrip%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?ppud=4))

With 4 Items and just show it on `MouseUp` event with:

```
contextMenuStrip1.Show(Cursor.Position);
```

Comment: Isn't context menu only applicable for right clicks?

Comment: @lakshyaleader No. As I mentioned, just call the `Show` function to display the context menu.
But normally it is used when right-clicking.

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

1. [This](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/17502/Simple-Popup-Control). You create a `Popup` form, which will be automatically hidden similar to popup menu and can host controls (buttons).
2. Display (draw) buttons inside your control, on top of its content (on top of graphics which you drawn), process mouse clicks, perform operations accordingly. Most difficult will be to draw *nice* looking buttons, to example, by using `VisualStyleRenderer` (xp-style).

Do not aks *big* question (containing many small one), rather try something, if it doesn't work or you are not satisfied with results, then come here and ask question (while also telling what you are trying to do). This way you will get help very quickly.

Comment: Article points out that we can't use form for this purpose here is the statement `When we show our popup form, the parent form loses its focus. A popup window should not cause that.`

Comment: Please read that sentence there again. You understand it in a wrong context.

Comment: I understood that my approach of using form making title bar as invisible would not work.. Rather I should use popup window.